# Returning a class

Tags: c++, class, function, return-value

We just started to study about classes in c++ and I have a little question about returning a class variable in function. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Medis{
private:
    int Aukstis;
    int Storis;
    int Amzius;
public:
    Medis();
    int GautiAuksti();
    int GautiStori();
    int GautiAmziu();

    bool NustatytiAuksti(int);
    bool NustatytiStori(int);
    bool NustatytiAmziu(int);   

    Medis SujungtiMedzius(Medis M1, Medis M2){
        Medis Grazinamas;
        Grazinamas.Aukstis = M1.Aukstis + M2.Aukstis;
        Grazinamas.Storis = M1.Storis + M2.Storis;
        Grazinamas.Amzius = M1.Amzius + M2.Amzius;
        return Grazinamas;
    }
};

int Medis::GautiAuksti(){return Aukstis;}
int Medis::GautiStori(){return Storis;}
int Medis::GautiAmziu(){return Amzius;}

bool Medis::NustatytiAuksti(int n){
    if (n >= 0){ 
        Aukstis = n;
        return true;
    }else return false;
}
bool Medis::NustatytiStori(int n){
    if (n >= 0){ 
        Storis = n;
        return true;
    }else return false;
}
bool Medis::NustatytiAmziu(int n){
    if (n >= 0){ 
        Amzius = n;
        return true;
    }else return false;
}

Medis::Medis(){
    Aukstis = 0;
    Storis = 0;
    Amzius = 0;
}

void main(){
    Medis Berzas[3];
    Berzas[0].NustatytiAuksti(10);
    Berzas[0].NustatytiStori(50);
    Berzas[0].NustatytiAmziu(23);
    printf("Aukstis = %d; Storis = %d; Amzius = %d", Berzas[0].GautiAuksti(), Berzas[0].GautiStori(), Berzas[0].GautiAmziu());
    Berzas[1].NustatytiAuksti(10);
    Berzas[1].NustatytiStori(50);
    Berzas[1].NustatytiAmziu(23);
    printf("Aukstis = %d; Storis = %d; Amzius = %d", Berzas[1].GautiAuksti(), Berzas[1].GautiStori(), Berzas[1].GautiAmziu());
    Berzas[2] = SujungtiMedzius(Berzas[0], Berzas[1]);
    cin.get();
}
```

And the error is at third line from back. Visual studio underlines the "SujungtiMedzius" (by the way I'm sorry that variables are not in English) and says: "identifier "SujungtiMedzius" is undefined". I were trying to find a way how to return a class object, but unsuccessfully. Is there a way to return a class object without any pointers? Or maybe you see some kind of miss type? I will appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: The function `SujungtiMedzius` is not a free function, it's part of a class. You should make it `static` and qualify the call with the class name: `Berzas[2] = Medis::SujungtiMedzius(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SujungtiMedzius is a member of Medis class so you need either provide object to call function like

```
Berzas[2] = Berzas[0].SujungtiMedzius(Berzas[0], Berzas[1]);
```

thru it doesn't make much sense as you don't use any data from Berzas[0]

or make SujungtiMedzius static and call it as

```
Berzas[2] = Medis::SujungtiMedzius(Berzas[0], Berzas[1]);
```

or, which is probably best option make SujungtiMedzius accepting only one parameter and use data from object it is called for as 2nd which should become something like

```
Berzas[2] = Berzas[0].SujungtiMedzius(Berzas[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

`SujungtiMedzius`  is a member function of `Medis` class and not `static`, it is in the scope of your `Medis` class. You have to call it with an instance of `Medis` class.